# Глюк при работе с Java

Tags: java

Windows XP Professional SP3
jdk1.7.0_80
jre7
Eclipse Luna

AMD Duron 1.8 ГГц
3 ГБ ОЗУ
NVIDIA GeForce FX 5200

Я недавно начал изучать Java, у меня старый компьютер но именно на этой машине всё прекрасно работало. Однако после переустановки Windows (на точно такую-же), корректной установки драйверов и установки Java, эта самая Java начала нехило глючить. Что я только не пробовал, результата нет.. Подробно в скриншотах.

[image: Java Control Panel]
[image: Запуск jar-файла]
[image: Запуск jar-файла]

Comment: Это вы замазали или это глюк такой?

Comment: В том-то и дело что это такой глюк, как будто бы кто-то замазал все эти строки. Я сначала подумал что это работа вируса, после многократных проверок оказалось что система чиста. С драйверами тоже всё в порядке. Уже и не знаю на что грешить..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сталкивался с подобным при запуске swing-приложения в терминале Windows Server 2003. Помог запуск с ключами

```
-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true
-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false
-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь, но я даже не знаю как это применить.. Подскажете?

Comment: Открываете консоль cmd, переходите командой cd в каталог с jar-файлом и выполняете `java -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -jar LotteryMachine.jar`

Comment: Сделал всё как Вы и указали. Вот результат:

C:\Documents and Settings\Вячеслав>cd /D d:/IT

D:\IT>java -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -jar LotteryMachine.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile LotteryMachine.jar

D:\IT>_

Comment: Ошибка значит, что в D:\IT нет этого jar-файла. Если верить скриншоту, то он у вас в `D:\IT\Java jar-files`

Comment: Да, именно так, это моя невнимательность. Спасибо Вам огромное, всё заработало как надо! Я так понимаю что теперь запускать jar-файлы придётся каждый раз именно таким образом, через командную строку, закрепить данные настройки по дефолту не получится? И где можно почитать за эти ключи, что это такое, очень интересно!

Comment: Можно создать обычный ярлык проводника Windows, в котором прописать эту команду. Грубо говоря, эти ключи указывают виртуальной машине, что для рендеренга окон нужно использовать OpenGL вместо DirectX.